# unable to use while loop or try except to find an spelling error in python

Tags: python, input, while-loop, spell-checking, try-except

```
def start():
    print("select any one of the operators: ")
    print("SI")
    print("BMI")
    print("AP")
    print('QE')
    s = 'SI'
    b = 'BMI'
    a = 'AP'
    q = 'QE'
    x = input('type the required operation: ')

try:
 intro = "select any one of the operators: "
 print(red + intro.upper())
 print('__________________________')
 print("SI(simple interest)")
 print("BMI(body mass index)")
 print("AP(arithmetic progression)")
 print("QE(quadratic equations)")
 print('__________________________')
 s =  'SI'
 b = 'BMI'
 a = 'AP'
 q = 'QE'
 yellow = '\033[33m'
 x = input(yellow + 'Type the required operation: ')
 if x.upper() == s:
     si()
 if x.upper() == b:
    bmi()
 if x.upper() == a:
    ap()
 if x.upper() == q:
    qe()
except :
    print('spelling error, please try again')
    start()
```

**I am trying to create a program where it lists four operations(simple interest, AP, quadratic equation, BMI) and asks input to the user. If the input didnt match any of the operation then it need to print spelling error and let the user try again to give an input. but if i type anything other than the operations the program just ends without printing anything. i have also tried using while loops but it also fails **

```
list = ['SI', 'BMI', 'AP', 'QE']
while x != list:
    print('spelling error')
    start()
    if x == list:
        break
```

please help me in finding a way to print spelling error and allow the user to try again

Comment: You need to use the `in` operator to test if an element belongs to a list.

Comment: Also, don't use `list` as a variable name in python.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `list` is a reserved keyword in python, so you can't use it for variable's name. Second, if you want to see whether the string is in a list, you must use the `in` keyword, not `==`. Your `start` function should return the `x`, or else the while loop won't recognize which `x` you're referring.

Here is an example if you want to do a spell checking using while loop:

```
x = ''
while True:
    print("select any one of the operators: ")
    print('__________________________')
    print("SI(simple interest)")
    print("BMI(body mass index)")
    print("AP(arithmetic progression)")
    print("QE(quadratic equations)")
    print('__________________________')
    x = input('type the required operation: ').upper()
    if x == "SI":
        si()
    elif x == "BMI":
        bmi()
    elif x == "AP":
        ap()
    elif x == "QE":
        qe()
    else:
        print("spelling error")
        continue
    break
```

Comment: You can use `list` as a variable name, but you shouldn't

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this for the input verification:

```
print ( 'type the required operation: ', end='')
while True: 
   inp = input()
   if not inp in ['AP','BMI','SE','QE']:
       print ("spelling error")
   else:
       break;
```

And then create and if, elif, else statement to select an action
If you want to allow your entries to be entered in lowercase as well, use for example:

```
if not inp.upper() in ['AP','BMI','SE','QE']:
```

Also, try to be consistent with spaces. If you've added 4 for the first indentation, try to use 4 also for the try-except block.

Statements under a try clause should also be as minimal as possible; add only the statement you actually want to test otherwise all other errors will also be caught, making it harder to debug, ie.

```
age = input('Your age ?')
try:
    age_int = int(age)
except:
    # error in converting string to int
    pass
else:
    # string was converted to an int without errors
    print (f'You claim to be {age_int} years')
```